# Problems running 110 V and 24 V PLC signals in same cable

Tags: ac, dc, cables, plc

Has anyone encountered issues running analog signals that are 110 VAC and 24 VDC together in the same cable on the way to their PLC inputs?

Let's imagine each signal could be like 100 mA. I know with supply lines this is a definite no go, but with the small amperages on the PLC 22AWG signal wires within a cable, what is the effect?

As a side note, I see this done all the time. I just want to understand if I **should** design this way or not, so I need to weigh the complexity of adding extra cables and plugs to a design.

***Update 1***

By popular request, where are some example links for controllers I've run into a lot. These are usually implemented in the field by being tied to a control transformer for the AC and a power source for the DC.

CPU: [H2-DM1E](https://www.automationdirect.com/adc/shopping/catalog/programmable_controllers/do-more_h2_-a-_t1h_(micro_modular_-a-_stackable)/cpus/h2-dm1e)

INPUT: [D2-16NA](https://www.automationdirect.com/adc/shopping/catalog/programmable_controllers/do-more_h2_-a-_t1h_(micro_modular_-a-_stackable)/ac_i-z-o/d2-16na)

OUTPUT: [D2-12TA](https://www.automationdirect.com/adc/shopping/catalog/programmable_controllers/do-more_h2_-a-_t1h_(micro_modular_-a-_stackable)/ac_i-z-o/d2-12ta)

Comment: 110 V analog signals sounds very unusual. So are 24 V analog signals. Standard industrial analog signals are 0 - 10 V and 4 - 20 mA. What's generating a 110 V AC analog signal?

Comment: By standard 'industrial signals' what you mean are the newest designs.  There are still tons of PLC's in market and installed everywhere (at least in the US) using 110V, 240V, and 24V control signals.  I'm guessing you're a younger designer, but the reality is many facilities just can't get to the types of controls you're talking about.  Do to EMF, grounding and existing cabling it would take scrapping the entire process and rebuilding to use low voltage controls.

Comment: It's 42 years since I qualified and I work for an American corporation in Europe and still support machines built in the 1980s. I've never seen 110 V analog signals though. What are they used for and how does analog work over AC?

Comment: @JamieMarshall If I called a wolf a sheep, does it make it less dangerous? Please leave data sheet links to the devices that produce 110 volt AC control signals. Maybe they are somehow current limited to make them safe? I'm aware of 24 volt DC and AC control signals and I've been in EE since about 1975.

Comment: Cables have capacitance between the conductors, so having a significant AC source in a conductor near a DC signal might have problems. You also have the issue of induction. For these reasons alone its considered bad JuJu. If you know precisely what cable, lengths signals etc, then you can make an informed decision.  if the conductor insulation is adequate for the voltage/current then you ok in that respect, but some codes prohibit mixing such signals. There’s also the issue of site termination and the safety for people working on the system. My advice - just don’t do it.

Comment: @Andyaka - I posted links to the product pages for a PLC and Cards that use 120V control.

Comment: Those cards are relay output and digital input - not what we’d call analog.  For a self contained system, switching mixed voltages is ‘acceptable’. It is not unusual for motor controls to have a mix of voltages- eg: 110V for the contactors and 24V for the switches and indicators. However if i had to send it down a cable I’d probably put a 24V relay at the contactor end to switch the contactor as contactors with 24VDC coils are generally much more expensive.

Comment: Checking in late here -- to clarify, you asked if anyone had any issues with this combination, and received an answer that seems to confirm such -- please mark it as an accepted answer if satisfactory; or explain how your question has not been answered so that a proper answer can be given; or modify the question to provide enough supporting information so that it can be answered better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Around here, code prohibits mains voltage and low voltage wires sharing the same conduit or the same cable.

One reason is that low voltage signals will be connected to devices which expect low voltage signals, so they don't take special precautions for insulation and safety. If low voltage and high voltage wires share a conduit or a cable, and someone drills the wall and hits the cable, or cuts it, or the cable gets worn and shorts, then these wires may short together, and high voltage may end up on devices that were not designed for it. The devices will most likely be destroyed, and this also creates a safety issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this doesn't help my issue.  There is no low voltage controls or mains being discussed in the question.  Only 110V and 24V 100ma control signals.

Comment: 110 V is mains voltage in North America though and can kill. 24 V won't in most circumstances. That's my reading of the situation too.

Comment: I'd say that if the cable is contained in a machine, it would be okay. But if the cable has to run in conduits or on the walls, you should check your local code.

Comment: @Transistor - again, these control devices use 110V but are limited at about 100ma (usually lower than that).  So even though it's 110V, it does not have the same considerations as a main.  My guess is its being produced by Triac's in the controller, because the voltage is quite high, even when the signal is in the off state (30-40V).  So it's just not the same as working with a main. (Unless I'm missing something).

Comment: Don’t underestimate the ability of the cable capacitance to induce a voltage.  Note that many electrical codes consider anything over 60V dangerous and thus treated the same as mains. I think your answer  will be dependant on your local electrical standards.  There may be grandfather clauses that cease when you make changes to the equipment.